# Where is chrome extension directory in windows 8?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, directory

I want to read the source code of chrome extensions. I m not able to find the directory where the extensions are stored.

I m using windows 8.

There is not AppData folder in C:\Users\\  and there is DocumentsandSetting folder in C:.

Comment: http://www.labnol.org/software/view-source-of-chrome-extension/21284/

Answer (score 8):

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\<VERSION>\Extensions\
```

or

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

Comment: There is JSON file in that location that too empty. There is no .crx file other than default extension file in the default apps folder.

Comment: maybe you'll find what you want there: c:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\

Comment: Thanks!!
The AppData folder was hidden in windows 8, thats the problem.

Answer (score 3):

========== If the above answer is not working =============

@mevas answer is correct, but in some cases it won't work.

For example:- If you have created more than one profile ( google account ) in the chrome browser then you can find the chrome extension source files in the 'Profile X' directory.
Path will be something like given below.

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1
```

Refer this [page](http://uncaughterror.com/programming/javascript/how-to-find-chrome-extension-location-in-our-computer/)

OR

Use the following steps to find the chrome extension directory.

1. Open your chrome browser and type this url  chrome://version/ then
   hit the enter key
2. Now it will show you a screen like given below
3. In this screen you see label 'Profile Path' , it will be your active chrome profile extension directory.

[image]

[image]